# Show that $\{x\in R^n : \langle Ax,x\rangle+\langle b,x\rangle+c=0\}$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional $C^\infty$ manifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, submanifold

Show that $V=\{x\in R^n :  \langle Ax,x\rangle+\langle b,x\rangle+c=0\}$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional $C^\infty$ manifold, if $A$ is symetric and inversible and $\theta=\langle b,A^{-1}b\rangle-4c \in R-\{0\}$.

I've tried to show that $g(x)=\langle Ax,x\rangle+\langle b,x\rangle+c$ is a submersion, i.e. $g^´(x)h=\langle 2Ax+b,h\rangle$ is a surjective linear transformation for all $x$. But i didn't find something good and i do not know how to use the hypotesis of $\theta$.

Sorry for my naivety, i'm just a biginner in analysis. Any hint?

Comment: Can you show that this is the zero set of a $C^\infty$ function?

Comment: This is exactly what i tried with that $g$

Comment: There's a mistake in the derivative; I think there should be a factor of 2 in front of $A$ (think about the case $A=I$). Now solve for $x$ in terms of $b$ and check if this point lies on your surface.

Comment: Your derivative isn't right; remember to use the "product rule" (and symmetry of $A$). Note that $Dg_x$ is a linear transformation $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$, so surjectivity is equivalent to not being the zero transformation, which happens if and only if the "stuff" in $Dg_x(h)=\langle\text{stuff},h\rangle$ is non-zero. Note also, that you only have to verify surjectivity for all $x\in V$, not all $x\in \Bbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is algebra: try to "complete" the square and write your function as
$$\langle A(x+ x_0), x+x_0\rangle - d$$
for some $x_0$ and $d$ that are to be determined. Now show that the condition given is equivalent to $d \ne 0$.

Now reduce to the problem:
$$Q(x) = \langle Ax , x\rangle = d$$
gives a submanifold if $d\ne 0$. At this step the only thing you use is that $Q$ is homogenous ( of degree $2$, but it works for any degree).